# Using custom Makefile with Eclipse/CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a project of multiple `.c` and `.h` files and I write my own makefile.

How can I configure Eclipse to use my makefile and my source files from their original locations?

Answer (score 43):

You can create a custom Makefile and make sure it's in your project root. Then you need to disable the auto generated makefiles. You can do that by going here:

`Project Properties (right click on project and select properties) -> C/C++ Build -> in that window uncheck "Generate Makefiles Automatically."`

To use your own targets you can open the View called "Make Target":

`Window -> Show View -> Make Target`

In that view you can create a new target that will use the corresponding target in your custom Makefile.

Comment: What if you dont have this view?

Comment: Make sure to show advanced settings first. In the left bottom corner of the properties pop-up there is an option to: "Show advanced settings"

Answer (score 20):

There is an option to create a project from existing makefiles: use the "Project Wizard" and select "Makefile project".

Comment: Does that let you edit your Makefile instead of having to do it Eclipse's way?

Comment: @Peter: you can edit your makefiles as you which and Eclipse doesn't touch it... at least that's how I have used it. Maybe there are esoteric options that I haven't touched yet :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can disable "Generate makefiles automatically" in eclipse project properties -> c/c++ build (builder settings.)

Answer (score 3):

In my latest attempt to compile a Cross ARM compile, I made a painful discovery on how to get this working.

First I created a "Makefile project with existing Code".  I selected the Cross ARM tool chain.  If I now open a console within Eclipse and make, it works.

Now to build within the GUI, I had to:

1. Change properties to Internal Builder, with Generate Makefile
           checked.
2. The settings option now offers Build Artifact tab.  pick executable with ${Project}.
3. Build.  This will result in error in link stage.
4. Switch the settings to External Builder, uncheck "Automatic Makefile generation"
5. Clean
6. Build

Answer (score 3):

All that you have to do is tell gmake to use your makefile.  The default command for Code Composer Studio is `${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake`.  Simply tell gmake to use your own makefile (e.g. `sri.mk`).  We do this with the -f option.  So the default command would become `${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -f ../sri.mk`

Note that Code Composer Studio is Eclipse based.

Here are the instructions:

1. project->properties->C/C++ Build
2. click on the 'Builder' tab
3. Un-select 'Use default build command"
4. Change the command to `${CCS_UTILS_DIR}/bin/gmake -f ../sri.mk`

[image: screen capture of gui settings]

Note that the build is kicked off from the `Debug` directory. The `Debug` directory contains the makefiles that are generated by Eclipse.  I put my makefile in the top level directory of the project so that's why I put `../` in `-f ../sri.mk`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, there might be a line that says `"default: esh $(PLUGIN_SO),"` or something along those lines depending on your project. I've found that changing the `"default"` to `"all"` will enable the project to compile too. This is a handy feature, eclipse :)