# Eclipse CDT : How to manage multiple main() functions in a single C++ project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, working-set

I am starting the developpement of a project which will be made of multiple modules. I will validate each of those modules with a dedicated testbench, each with their main() function.
I would like to avoid having one Eclipse project for each testbench and its main() function.

I read about [Working Sets](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm) and the idea of showing only the files concerned for a particular testbench in my project is what I search for.

However, during the build phase, Eclipse continues building all the project files, not the current Working Set files only. I then have a Linker error because of multiple main() functions.

How can I configure Eclipse to Build the files of a Working Set only?
Is there another way to build multiple programs separately in a single project, i.e. an application and its components testbenches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building multiple binaries within one Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424795/building-multiple-binaries-within-one-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to deal with multiple main functions in Eclipse CDT by writting a custom [makefile](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_makefile.htm). It is a potential solution for C/C++ projects dealing with a main application and its components testbenches, for instance.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867990/using-custom-makefile-with-eclipse-cdt) how to specify a custom makefile in Eclipse.
Then, define a main rule (see [makefile](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_makefile.htm) documentation) building your whole application (without the testbenches) and define one additional rule for each of your testbenches (with its component) to be built.
To summarize : define one rule in your makefile for each of your main function, building the main and its dependencies.