# can we have multiple files in one package and folder structure in Eclipse?

Tags: c

To All IT Gurus,

I am trying to execute 2 .C files in one project in Eclipse. I get error. So, for example, Let us say I have this below code.

Both files 1 and 2 are in the same project First C Project, Is this allowed.??

Project Name - First_C_Project

```
File 1 = Example.C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {


printf ("C Programming, This is my First C Program");

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


File 2: TestProgram.C


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void) {


printf ("This is a TEST C Program, Check it out. ");

return 0;
}
```

I created a new project with a File 2 C file. And that works. But why can't I put the 2 C files work within the same First_C_Project project ???

Comment: You want the same project to have 2 executables? if so, why? Also *conio.h* is an old header that is not portable and you are not using it in your code anyway so don't include it.

Comment: okay. thank u. I will remove conio.h , so ur saying conio.h  is not used anymore by developers ?     ur question why?  I am just curious to see If it will work? then do I just create a new project with File #2? Correct?

Comment: *conio.h* was never used by developers AFAIK.

Comment: And it depends, DO YOU WANT 2 EXECUTABLES? Or you simply want to organize your code in different files?

Comment: Just want to organize my code in different files. How can I achieve that. ?

Comment: The answer below was correct then, but unfortunately it has been deleted!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be correct? I would like to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that you have 2 c files, but that you have 2 "main" functions.

If you want to have more than one main, look here:

[Eclipse CDT : How to manage multiple main() functions in a single C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789104/eclipse-cdt-how-to-manage-multiple-main-functions-in-a-single-c-project)

If you don't need two main functions, simply comment/rename/delete the on you are not using.

Comment: Okay, thank u.  So, If I want to execute my File #2 hello world program. How can I do so without the main function and still have both c files in one project.?   Hope I am making sense.